# How to save part of an html page to an image or pdf either on client (javascript) or asp.net on the server side?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Is there a way to implement functionality so that a user can Right click a subsection of an Html page (say a DIV or other container element) so that that part can be saved as an image/pdf (using javascript)?

Alternatively (ideally)  can this be done on the server side in ASP.NET?

The use case for this is the following:

I have some complex web pages generated in asp.NET and using the javscript Flot library for the graphs.  I would like to reuse part of the html page to generate PDF reports or at least image snapshots which can easily be inserted into reports.  I have looked around and it seems there is a tool wkhmltopdf which converts the entire page to PDF, however there are 2 issues:

1. This tool needs to be run separately, which is not friendly for end users
2. The tool extracts everything on the page, e.g. menus headers , footers etc.

For the second problem I could generate web pages without the headers/footers and menus, and then use the tool, but this does not solve problem 1.  Ideally I would like to generate the report weekly and automatically so the user only needs to download it.

For this purpose what is really needed is some way to  store as pdf or image a DIV (or other element) referenced by id.  This way I would not need to write separate code to generate the reports.  I realize there will be a loss of quality converting html to PDF, but for our purposes, this is not that important.

Answer (score 0):

IECapt# is a new and experimental version of IECapt written in C# to render a web page into a BMP, JPEG or PNG image file.

see http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/

You will have to make some calculations, if you want to crop the captured image to your requirements, or give the tool the html u actually want as an image,instead of the whole page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case this can help others, I finally settled for the iTextSharp library which is very powerful and also handles svg.  It does not do the general html5 to pdf dump but with a bit of code I can do most of what I need.

main website is:
http://itextpdf.com/

download:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/